# How to treat damped internal walls before painting?

Tags: walls, painting, paint, repainting, water-damage

Kitchen sanitary inwall PVC tube from above floor melted for some unknown reason, and so water entered walls for around a 1.3 year and caused damping on the first 20cm of all walls, as a result, the Emulsion paint peeled off.

Its been a year since the PVC tube was replaced and walls got fairly dry *(i assume it takes 5+ years to be fully dry)*.

Now i would like to repaint all walls with lime paint.

An expert suggested to use a breathable plaster to treat the walls (the expert wasn't aware of my will to use lime paint and assumed emulsion paint).

The manufacturer that produce the breathable plaster suggested to use their material by removing the 1 cm thick plaster (until the concrete blocks) up till 40 cm on all damped walls, then add a breathing plaster material and paint with lime paint.

Wouldn't a repaint only with lime paint act in the same sense?

Comment: Why do you think you know more than the expert? If you are given good advice, why not follow it? Or you think it is just too much work?

Comment: No idea why it would take _years_ to dry out if the pipe was fixed.  If it's still damp, you still have a moisture issue.

Comment: its a basement floor, Humidity is relatively higher - so i used dehumidifier. @SolarMike The 1st Expert wasn't aware that i will be using lime paint, and assumed Emulsion paint and so suggested to use breathing plaster. The 2nd expert is actually the manufacturer of the breathing plaster - it didnt make sense for me - maybe the plaster is not needed if using the lime paint?

Comment: Breathing plaster needs a paint that breathes as well otherwise either the plaster traps the moisture or the paint does.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, for this reason i am confused and want more opinions on this before i start taking old plaster off. If the idea is to allow wall to breath out its moisture - and for this reason the emulsion paint peeled off, then maybe the lime paint alone would sort it out?